# how to display repeated element postions in an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

how to display repeated elements with their index position in an array in c# console

I have this problem 
in simple c#
user has given me 5 numbers and  stored in an array and now i gave user the option to check the numbers with respect to its position

Now the problem is if in the 5 numbers user had stored earlier has 2 or more same numbers..how do i display those both with their positions?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[5];
            int check = 0;
            int position = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 elements");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int value;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter no to search");
            value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (value==arr[i])
                {
                    {
                        check = 1;
                        position = i;

                    }
                }
            }
            if (check == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("number is found At position " +position);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not found");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

please help me

If user entered the numbers as 1 2 3 1 2
and they are stored
then when user searches nos
it should display number is found at position of 1st  and 2nd??
help

Answer (score 0):

You can output the indices of the found numbers in your check loop like this:

```
bool check = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (value==arr[i])
    {
        check = true;
        Console.WriteLine("number is found At position {0}", i);
     }
}
if (!check) Console.WriteLine("Number not found at all.");
```

Or you save the indices in a list and output it afterwards:

```
List<int> foundIndices = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (value==arr[i])
        foundIndices.Add(i);
}
if (foundIndices.Count > 0)
    foreach(int index in foundIndices)
        Console.WriteLine("Number found at {0}", index);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Number not found at all.");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find repetitions you can try using *Linq*:

```
  int[] source = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1};

  var result = source.Select((item, index) => new {
    item = item,
    index = index
  })
  .GroupBy(v => v.item, v => v)
  .Where(chunk => chunk.Count() >= 2)
  .OrderBy(chunk => chunk.Key)
  .Select(chunk => String.Format("item {0} appears at {1} positions", 
     chunk.Key, 
     String.Join(", ", chunk.Select(v => v.index))));

  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);

  // item 1 appears at 0, 6, 7 positions
  // item 3 appears at 2, 4 positions
  Console.Write(report);
```

Comment: Hey bro please tell me some more simple method using system only like the way i have written without var or bool as begginers task

Answer (score 0):

```
//Used to track position of found numbers
var currentPosition = 0;
//Keeps the indexes 
var foundIndexes = new List<int>();
//Some dummy data
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7};
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
       if (numbers[i] == value)
       {
           foundIndexes.Add(i);
       }
    }
//can use the LINQ for each if you like it better (I do)
foundIndexes.ForEach(index =>
{
     Console.WriteLine("number is found At position " + index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of how you could do this using LINQ:

```
var appearsMoreThanOnce = arr
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => Enumerable.Range(1, arr.Length)
        .Where(i => arr[i-1] == v))
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Count() >= 2);

foreach (var number in appearsMoreThanOnce)
    Console.WriteLine(number.Key + " appears at: " + string.Join(",", number.Value));
```

LINQ can be pretty daunting, especially if you are new - I can elaborate further on how this solution works if it helps.